# Google Direction Service - Route from current location to defined destination

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my script which currently displays a route for either car or transit depending on what the user has selected.

Would anyone know how to adapt this script to set the origin as the users current location and route from that to set lat + long destination.

As I have currently been unable to find a way to integrate this within my script - any help would be much appreciated!

```js
      function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
          
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {lat: *VALUE*, lng: *VALUE*}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function() {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        });
      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
        directionsService.route({
          origin: {lat: *VALUE*, lng: *VALUE*},  // Haight.
          destination: {lat: *VALUE*,lng: *VALUE*},  // Ocean Beach.
          // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
          // using square brackets and a string value as its
          // "property."
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode],
           transitOptions: {
           arrivalTime: new Date(1489242600000),
           routingPreference: 'FEWER_TRANSFERS'
        },
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
             provideRouteAlternatives: true
        }, function(response, status) {
            
          if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696379/get-directions-to-predefined-destination-from-current-location-geolocation This answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

In the google directions API you can read what parameters you can add. In your case you would need origin and destination and maybe waypoints if you are planning to make a route with multiple stops.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

In the link below there is an example how you can select multiple way points. For the location you can use Geolocation to get the latitude and longitude. Those can be implemented in the calculateAndDisplay function in the origin parameter.

```
directionsService.route({
          origin: //here you can put lat/long or a name
          destination: //here you can put lat/long or a name
          waypoints: // waypoints expect an Array of locations or lat/long
          optimizeWaypoints: true,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
},
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints